# access base class protected nested class from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, protected

guys, I encountered this problem on a tech blog,the question asked what are the correct solution to resolve the compiler error generated in the below code. I have searched for hours and can not get an answer.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
     int data;
protected:
     class Nest
     {
        public:
           int nested;
     };
public:
     static Nest* createNest(){return new Nest;}
};

void use_someclass()
{
    SomeClass::Nest* nst = SomeClass::createNest();
    nst->nested = 5;
}

A.    Make function void use_someclass() a friend of class SomeClass.
B.    Make the function createNest() a non-static function of SomeClass.
C.    Declare the class Nest in public scope of class SomeClass.
D.    Make the object nst a reference object, and make the function 
      createNest() return a Nest&.
E.    Derive a class from SomeClass. Make the object nst a derived class
      pointer so that it can access SomeClass's protected declarations.
```

C is certainly right and trival.
I believe A is also right, and espectially E is a classic way of doing this kind of things.
I want implement what is said in E, but have a few difficulites. (I hope someone can also implement the idea in A), below is my code:

```
class derived:public SomeClass{};
void use_someclass()
{
   derived::Nest  *nst=SomeClass::createNest();
   nst->nested = 5;
}
```

in the above, the idea is we can access the Nest definition from a derived class.
in function use_someclass(), in the first line, the right hand side is a static function, and returns type Nest*, but on the left hand side, I don't know how to match the right hand side type.  "derived::Nest" is wrong. compiler error: can not access protected member. Nest is only a definition in SomeClass, not member.

what can we use to replace "derived::Nest"? derived certainly saw the definition of Nest, but I don't know how to "say" it. Maybe somehow via "this" pointer.

Comment: You can declare use_someclass in class derived to use Nest.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility in your derived class:

```
class derived : public SomeClass {
  public:
    using SomeClass::Nest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found this after some search yesterday."Using SomeClass::Nest" works. Do we have other choice? "Using" breaks the protected qualifier.